# Displaying a JavaScript created element inline (click not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the "Hotel Datepicker" script from here: http://lopezb.com/hoteldatepicker/

I'm trying to display the datepicker inline (e.g. displaying all the time and not closing when dates are selected).

I've added a function which is called when the datepicker closes to click on the input field (which opens the datepicker when clicked on). The datepicker does stay open but is not usable after the first set of dates have been selected.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ngu48heq/1/

```
var daterangepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('daterangepicker'), {
                disabledDates: ['2018-04-20','2018-04-21','2018-04-22','2018-04-23','2018-04-29','2018-04-30'],
                enableCheckout: true,
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            });

            var input = document.getElementById('daterangepicker');

            input.addEventListener('afterClose', function () {
                $('#daterangepicker').click();
            }, false);
```

FYI the datepicker isn't using the jQueryUI standard "datepicker" script which I am aware has a built in inline option.

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong it would much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the click event is messing with the plugin's event listeners. In any case, I've tried the following, and it seems to do what you require:

```
var daterangepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('daterangepicker'), {
            disabledDates: ['2018-04-20','2018-04-21','2018-04-22','2018-04-23','2018-04-29','2018-04-30'],
            enableCheckout: true,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('daterangepicker');

        input.addEventListener('afterClose', function () {
            daterangepicker.open(); //use the library's own API
        }, false);
```

Let me know if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

The 'afterClose' method is for executing methods after closing the datepicker. And you are dynamically setting up a click operation on the datepicker which doesnt let the datepicker to close.

```
var daterangepicker = new HotelDatepicker(document.getElementById('daterangepicker'), {
                    disabledDates: ['2018-04-20','2018-04-21','2018-04-22','2018-04-23','2018-04-29','2018-04-30'],
                    enableCheckout: true,
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                });

            var input = document.getElementById('daterangepicker');

            input.addEventListener('afterClose', function () {
               // Commented the following line, makes the code work. 
               // $('#daterangepicker').click();
            }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/ngu48heq/10/